# Custom Svelte material UI Slider label

Tags: javascript, material-ui, svelte

I need to set custom label of smui/slider https://sveltematerialui.com/demo/slider/ in a tick marks and discrete slider. I've found explained hot to do it in material web components https://github.com/material-components/material-components-web/tree/v13.0.0/packages/mdc-slider and it seems that is possible using **setValueToAriaValueTextFn** but there isn't any example, and even less using svelte.

How can I do it?

Thank's in advance

Comment: In [https://github.com/hperrin/svelte-material-ui/blob/master/packages/slider/src/Slider.svelte](https://github.com/hperrin/svelte-material-ui/blob/master/packages/slider/src/Slider.svelte) there is a function prop that seems to do it:

` export let valueToAriaValueTextFn: (value: number) => string = (value) =>
    `${value}`;`
Maybe it have to bind this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is unfortunately not possible to change the tooltip text with https://sveltematerialui.com/demo/slider/ .

The tooltip text is bound to `value`.
See here: https://github.com/hperrin/svelte-material-ui/blob/master/packages/slider/src/Slider.svelte#L181

```
<span class="mdc-slider__value-indicator-text">{value}</span>
```

The `value` is exported by the component and you could modify it, but this would of course only allow for numbers and would also change the current value/position of the slider -> which would mess up it's functionality.